# Why are my eigenvectors not orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I plotted the eigenvectors:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1.809 & 3.464 &  0.485 \\
 0.603 & 3.464 & -0.728 \\
 0.603 & 3.464 &  0.485 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I used the numbers in the top row as $x$-coordinates, the 2nd row for $y$-coordinates, and the 3rd row for $z$-coordinates.

I noticed that they didn't appear to be at right angles, so I computed the cosine, and then degrees, between each pair of vectors. The degrees between each pair were (rounded) 100, 121, and 82.

Why are the degrees between each pair of eigenvectors not 90 degrees, the way that $x$, $y$, and $z$ Cartesian axes are? Is that not what's meant by "orthogonal"?

Comment: Eigenvectors aren't always orthogonal, that requires assumptions about the matrix you started with (and sometimes even about the way you select "the" eigenvectors).

Comment: Ah okay, looks like my issue is that my data matrix is non-symmetric. Should have googled it first but your comment led me there. Thanks.

Comment: Since you mention the word data in this context, some buzzwords that might also lead to productive googling are "PCA" and "SVD".

Comment: You don't mention the matrix of which these are the eigenvectors, and you don't mention what the word "orthogonal" has to do with your problem.